# Rails and Importing CSV issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

This seems to be a very small error but I cannot find any solution to this problem.. I am trying to use the CSV gem in my rails(3.2) application(ruby 1.9.3) and I am getting an error "NoMethodError". My controller is:

```
require 'csv'

def import
  file = params[:file] <-- error
  CSV.parse(file, :headers => false) do |row|
      Event.new(:Ename => row[0], :Edate => row[1], :Elocation => row[2], :Edesc => row[3], :Oname => row[4], :Oemail => row[5], :Odetail => row[6])
  end
end
```

I am getting this file from a view where the users can upload the csv file. I am getting a NoMethodError(undefined method 'nil' for nil:NilClass). My best guess is I am using this method wrong, but then my next question is how to parse the Csv data? I want to retrieve the file from my view and then parse the data into the database. How can I open the file for the same? Is the above method not correct?
A quick note, I tried using the 'FasterCSV' gem but I got a "Use the standard FasterCsv 1.9.2 gem". I had to change from fastercsv to the standard csv as the gem deployment to heroku was giving a problem.

Forgot to give the view file,

```
<%= form_tag({:action => :import}, :multipart => true) do %>
<%= file_field_tag 'file' %>
<% end %>
```

It's basic. The error I am getting is on the parse method.. I did look at the documentation and saw that I am supposed to use a string. But I thought that 'params[:file]' gives me that. Sorry, I am relatively new to Rails..

Comment: My best bet is that your application is not receiving the file you are uploading. Can you share your view code please?

Comment: The error message will tell you the file and line number that caused the error to be raised. If you can share that it will make it easier to suggest solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can be like the following:

```
if request.post? && params[:file].present?
  infile = params[:file].read

  CSV.parse(infile) do |row|

  end
end
```

Comment: This works perfect. THANKS tommasop.. But now I have another question, this time regarding saving the csv data. I am using the this code to store the data,
Event.new(:Ename => row[0], :Edate => row[1], :Elocation => row[2], :Edesc => row[3], :Oname => row[4], :Oemail => row[5], :Odetail => row[6])
The logs show that this was passed. But my database doesn't store the data.. Would you know why?

Comment: I checked the heroku logs, they don't show any problems.. It shows a Completed 200 status after the controller event. The only issue which it shows is cache: [POST/events/import] invalidate, pass. Any ideas what this means? THANKS A LOT

Comment: NM got it! I thought .new does a save. But it works.. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

CSV.parse expects a string not a file http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html, try CSV.read instead

@tommasop also correct and your file might not be persisted on the filesystem. Make sure its saved first

Comment: It is not necessary to persist the file on the file system you can process it directly.